# Wiping a char*, while keeping the string

Tags: c

I need help figuring out how to wipe or reset a `char*`, but keep the value of the `char*` in a `struct`.

For example if I have

```
char* word;
struct test *person;
word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
person = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
```

let's say I store the word 'Jack' in word using a function, as I use the read function to read from a CSV.

So ...

```
while (read(STDIN, buffer, 1) != 0) {
    add(word, *buffer);
}

void add(char* string, char c) {
    int size = strlen(string);
    string[size] = c;
    string[size + 1] = '\0';
}

person->name = word;
memset(word, 0, sizeof(word));
```

Doing this empties the string in person->name as well as word.

How can I keep the string in `person->name`?

I've tried creating a separate string, but was unable to resolve the issue.

```
char temp[size];
int i = 0;
while (word[i] != '\0') {
    temp[i] = word[i];
    i++;
}
```

This also clears the string in `person->name` as well as temp.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your attempt at copying the string, you forgot to put a null terminator at the end of `temp`. You should use `strdup` or `strcpy` instead anyway. Also, if `temp` goes out of scope, it's no longer safe, so you need to `malloc` it instead of just defining it on the stack.

Comment: @JoshChoi "let's say I store the word 'Jack' in word." how do you do that?

Comment: you can reinitialize word with new memory location ... this way you can reuse the same pointer without affecting the old memory location

Comment: @Swordfish I am reading in from a csv and setting appending word from the buffer.

Comment: @JoshChoi i meant exactly that: "let's say I store the word 'Jack' in word." how?

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan How can I do this?

Comment: @Swordfish  I have a function add that adds to word from buffer. so I call on add(word,buffer) and add is....

void add(char* string, char c){
 int size = strlen(string);
 string[size] = c;
 string[size+1] = '\0';
}

Comment: `word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` in place of `memset(word,0,sizeof(word));`

Comment: @JoshChoi how do you allocate memory for the string?

Comment: @JoshChoi `word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` why you are allocating space for only one character . There is no space to store the string

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan I misswrote the malloc statement above. I am allocating more than enough space in my code. Also, I tried replacing memset with  word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*50);  and it resulted in a seg fault.

Comment: @Swordfish  person->name=(char*)malloc(sizeof(word));

Comment: @JoshChoi segFault at same line or another line.

Comment: @JoshChoi: Forget `sizeof(char)`, it is always `1`. `sizeof(word)` in your call to `malloc()` is wrong because it won't give you the size of the memory, `word` points to nor the length of the string stored in it but the size of a `char*` which is most likely `4` or `8`.

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan Different line, I was not getting a segfault before.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> person->name = word;
> memset(word, 0, sizeof(word));
> ```

If you want to make a copy of `word` for `person->name` you have to allocate memory first:

```
person->name = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);  // + 1 for the terminating '\0'
```

then you can copy the string pointed to by `word` to the memory now pointed to by `person->name`:

```
strcpy(person->name, word);
```

Then you can set `word`s length to `0`:

```
word[0] = '\0';
```

and reuse `word`.

Make sure that you `free()` all memory you allocated with `malloc()` when it is no longer needed.

---

> ```
> void add(char* string, char c) {
>     int size = strlen(string);
>     string[size] = c;
>     string[size + 1] = '\0';
> }
> ```

This function is unsafe because it potentially writes beyond the bounds of the memory allocated for `string`. Give it another parameter which denotes the size of it:

```
#include <stdbool.h>  // bool
#include <stddef.h>   // size_t
#include <string.h>   // strlen()

bool add(char* string, size_t size, char ch)
{
    size_t length = strlen(string);

    if (length + 2 > size)
        return false;

    string[length] = ch;
    string[length + 1] = '\0';
    return true;
}
```